# Regex string get content between characters

Tags: regex

I have string:

```
str = 'select(a,b,c).where(d,e,f).order(i,j,k)'
```

What the regex can i get `a,b,c` and `d,e,f` and `i,j,k`?

```
{
   select: 'a,b,c',
   where: 'd,e,f',
   order: 'i,j,k'
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: What condition and rules are you wanting, just anything between `(...)`?

Comment: did you mean [`(\w+)\((.*?)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/EVUMJg/1)

Answer (score 0):

To capture `a,b,c` and `d,e,f` and `i,j,k` I think you use a capturing group:

[`\(([^\)]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bFRY2L/1)

- Match an opening parenthesis `\(`
- Start a capturing group `(`
- Match until you encounter a closing parenthesis) `[^\)]+`
- Close the capturing group `)`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear what you want exactly, but I guess maybe something like:

```
var str = 'select(a,b,c).where(d,e,f).order(i,j,k)';
str = "{\n\t" + str.replace(/\(/g, ": '").replace(/\)/g, "'").replace(/\./g, ",\n\t") + "\n}";
console.log(str);
```

Prints:

```
{
    select: 'a,b,c',
    where: 'd,e,f',
    order: 'i,j,k'
}
```